# iOS in app purchases

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

This might not be relevant to this site, but hopefully you guys can point me in the right direction, or even have experience with the something similar.

We have an app that we can't put registration on because apple want's their cut in the profits, i.e. they want their 30%

But the markup we have on the item for sale is so low that if we give apple 30% we will actually be loosing money.

The question I have then is it allowed to charge more for an item if it is available as an in app purchase than the selling price on our site?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally Apple said you couldn't charge more on the app store, but the latest version of the developer guidelines has removed that restriction, so it should be fine to charge more on the app store so that you cover your costs.

What you can't do is mention anywhere in the app that the user can buy it cheaper from your site.

You can see the exact terms in this document (you'll need to log in with your developer account to see it). The bit relating to in-app purchase is under section 11. Purchasing and currencies:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

The relevant part is quoted below (note that Apple may change these guidelines at any time):

11.12
Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases, as set forth in the Developer Program License Agreement.

11.13
Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

11.14
Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app, as long as there is no button or external link in the app to purchase the approved content. Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues for approved content that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app

Answer (score 0):

That would be kind of cheating..
Come up with schemes of combined items from your site to match apple's own..otherwise drop the idea..either you will go bankrupt or your customer will be :D (well not exactly..but you got the point)

Comment: Haha I know what you mean, we can always go legal with apple, I know of a company in SA who did it and was allowed to continue, but we are way smaller than them. Also combined items might be the solution we are looking for but then still in the end the markup is to low to really make a difference, but luckily most of the user base will use the web app